# $\log(\frac{n}{n-1}) = \Theta (\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

$\log(\frac{n}{n-1}) = \Theta (\frac{1}{n})$

---

The definition for $\Theta$ is $\exists n_0,C: |f(n)| \leq C \cdot g(n) \space\forall n \geq n_0$ and $|g(n)| \leq C_2 \cdot f(n)$.

I solved similar problems already but I'm not very good with logarithms and I'm not sure how to do this one.

Not sure if it helps but we can write $\frac{n}{n-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{n-1}$.

We want to show $\log(1 + \frac{1}{n-1}) \leq C \cdot \frac{1}{n}$.

Can we do this? $1 + \frac{1}{n-1} \leq 2^{ \space C \cdot \frac{1}{n}}$. I don't know what to do now or if this even made sense. I know that $2n \leq 2^{n}$, this looks similar and I guess you can say the same about $n^{-1}$. No matter what C we choose $2n \geq 2^{n}$ is impossible. $  (\frac{1}{n}) \leq C \cdot \log(\frac{n}{n-1})$ would also be impossible by that logic. But I think that $\log(\frac{n}{n-1}) = \Theta (\frac{1}{n})$ is true because I graphed the functions, so I guess I missed something.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the limit definition of $\Theta$

Comment: yea that's fine

Comment: Uhhh I used L'Hopital and the limit is $1$, this means that the statement is true. But I would still like to know how I can do it with the other definition. And I have another stupid question: What's the difference between $\lim$ and $\lim \sup$? And why is $\lim \sup$ used for $O$ and only $\lim$ for $o$?